# Qt Writing mouse position to file

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

I'm writing a simple application using QT that should write the mouse position inside certain widget to a file (the writing is on user double click).

The situation is as follows:

- The user performs double click inside the widget.
- In the Debug window i can see the current mouse position.
- The mouse position is written to the file as expected.

The issue when the mouse position (X or Y) is less then 100. In case that the position is less then 100 the number that is written to the file is always 3 digits number.

For example: Mouse position in the debug window is: 34, 251 and in the file the position is 344, 251. So i can't predict if the actual X position was 34 or 344 because both of them are valid values.

This is the part that responsible on writing the data to the file.

```
QByteArray temp1;
char buf[2];
::sprintf(buf, "%d", X);  // X is the mouse x position
temp1.append(buf);
temp1.append(",");
::sprintf(buf, "%d", Y); // Y is the mouse y position
temp1.append(buf);
...
if (tempFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    QTextStream stream(&tempFile);
    stream << temp1;
}
tempFile.close();
```

This code works good only for positions larger then 100 for some reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**

The buffer is too small.

```
char buf[2];
```

There needs to be place for multiple digits and a terminating NUL byte, since your are using sprintf here:

```
::sprintf(buf, "%d", X);
```

Writing over the end of the array results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So you need to increase the size of the array to fix it.

**Problem 2**

- the file is opened in ReadWrite mode
- the X and Y value are written
- the file is closed

The next time the values are written the same operations are called. ReadWrite mode does not delete the existing contents of the file. For example if you write once

```
128,1024
```

and then the next time you write the position: 60,30 it would look like this:

```
60,3024
```

One possible solution for this problem would be to apply `Truncate` mode.

```
if (tempFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate)) {
```

Comment: Thanks, currently the buffer size is 20 (char buf[20];) and still i'm getting the same result

Comment: I added the description of the second problem plus a possible solution to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan Schlecht after i added the Truncate the problem solved.